# How to check if entity framework 5 is running with .net framework 4.5

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.5

I am confusing if entity framework 5 is based on .net framework 4.5 or .net framework 4.0 in my project, because when I added ef5 to my project from nuget, it shows the run time version is v4.0.30319 as in attached image.  (I assume it should be v4.5.50709?)

In the project settings, the targeted framework is correctly set to .Net Framework 4.5 and I am using visual studio 2012.

If it is not using .net framework 4.5. How I can do to make sure it is using .net framework 4.5? Thanks for your help.

[image: here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 4.5 Runtime. The 4.5 Framework is built ontop of the 4.0 Runtime and CLR. What you are [seeing is expected](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx).